# How to export dynamics into D3

Tags: graphics, export

Are there any existing examples or 3rd party repositories that attempt to make this possible at any level?

**Update:** 
This is different from the linked question because it specifically asks for D3 integration/exportation.

Comment: I have seen a Mathematica export to plotly.js -- which is based on D3.js. You might google and find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can test this package to interact with Plotly:

https://github.com/Nevensky/plotly-mathematica

Plotly JS code now is open source.

**Update:**

This package is a single function, and a hello world didn't work:
[image]